# df with dictionaries as elements - extract specific key values from rows

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

So I have the following json file:

```
{
"result":{
    "segments":[
        {
            "speaker":"#Tag#",
            "language":"",
            "start":0.10,
            "end":0.20,
            "words":[
                {
                    "start":0.10,
                    "end":0.20,
                    "word":"(music)",
                    "conf":1.00
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "speaker":"14",
            "language":"EN",
            "start":0.51,
            "end":7.01,
            "words":[
                {
                    "start":0.51,
                    "end":0.69,
                    "word":"Some",
                    "conf":1.00
                },
                {
                    "start":0.69,
                    "end":0.93,
                    "word":"sentence",
                    "conf":1.00
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "speaker":"13",
            "language":"EN",
            "start":7.02,
            "end":127.35,
            "words":[
                {
                    "start":7.02,
                    "end":7.59,
                    "word":"Some",
                    "conf":0.97
                },
                {
                    "start":7.59,
                    "end":7.74,
                    "word":"other",
                    "conf":1.00
                },
                {
                    "start":126.93,
                    "end":127.35,
                    "word":"sentence.",
                    "conf":1.00
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "speaker":"13",
            "language":"EN",
            "start":671.05,
            "end":671.71,
            "words":[
                {
                    "start":671.05,
                    "end":671.71,
                    "word":"end",
                    "conf":1.00
                 }
             ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I normalized the file with pandas using json_normalize until I've reached the level of the information that I want to extract, like so:

```
df = pd.read_json(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/json-to-parse.json')
turns = json_normalize(df['result'])
sentence = json_normalize(turns.T[0])

words = json_normalize(sentence['words'])     
words.insert(0, 'speaker', sentence['speaker'])
```

Which gives me a data frame with dictionaries as elements, like so:

[image]

What I now what is to only get the values of the key 'word' inside every dictionary, and join the columns to get the full sentences of each row. However, I cannot seem to be able to extract the 'word' value of all dictionaries in the rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think [pandas.DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) will help you. Try this one:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

data = json.loads(open('your_json.json').read())
df = pd.DataFrame(data['result']['segments'])
df['word'] = (df['words'].explode()
              .apply(lambda x: x['word'])
              .groupby(level=0)
              .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x)))
```

And you will get:

[image]